# change name if exists when creating a txt file in Vbs

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a program that gets user input and saves it in a text document, every time it saves a new document I want the file name to change

Here is what I have:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso
Dim firstNameInput
Dim lastNameInput
Dim count
Dim testPath
Dim exists
Dim fileName
Dim fileStream
Dim filePath

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

firstNameInput = inputbox("Please enter your name")
lastNameInput = inputbox("Enter your last name")

count = 1
do
    testPath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Info\peopleInfo" & count & ".txt"
    exists = fso.FolderExists(testPath)
    if(exists) then
        count + 1
    else
        exit do
    end if
loop

fileName = "peopleInfo" & count & ".txt"
filePath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Info\"
Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath & fileName)

fileStream.WriteLine firstNameInput
fileStream.WriteLine lastNameInput
fileStream.Close
```

What I have doesn't seem to be working...

So every time I open this program, I want it to save the file as `peopleInfo1` then `peopleInfo2` then `peopleInfo3` , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
    Option Explicit
    Const RootFolder = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Info"
    Dim fso,Folder,FirstFile,sFile,sFileNewName,firstNameInput,lastNameInput
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(RootFolder) Then
        fso.CreateFolder(RootFolder)
    End If
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(RootFolder)
    Do
        firstNameInput = inputbox("Please enter your name")
    Loop Until firstNameInput <> ""

    Do
        lastNameInput = inputbox("Enter your last name")
    Loop Until lastNameInput <> ""

    FirstFile = RootFolder &"\peopleInfo.txt"
    If Not fso.FileExists(FirstFile) Then
        Call Write2File(RootFolder & "\peopleInfo.txt")
    Else
        sFileNewName = GetNewName(FirstFile)
        Call Write2File(sFileNewName)   
    End If
    '************************************************************************************************************
    Function GetNewName(sFile)
        Dim snamebase,sname,Count,sTarget,MaxIncrementation
        MaxIncrementation = 1000
        snamebase = Split(Right(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile,"\")),".")(0)
        sname = snamebase
        Count = 0
        While Count < MaxIncrementation
            sTarget = Folder & "\" & sname & ".txt"
            If fso.FileExists(sTarget) Then
                Count = Count + 1
                sName = snamebase & "(" & Count & ")"
            Else
                GetNewName = sTarget
                Exit Function
            End If
        Wend
    End Function
    '************************************************************************************************************
    Sub Write2File(File)
        Dim fileStream
        Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(File)
        fileStream.WriteLine firstNameInput
        fileStream.WriteLine lastNameInput
        fileStream.Close
    End Sub
    '************************************************************************************************************
```

Or Something like that :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,fso,RootFolder,Folder,FirstFile,sFile,sFileNewName,firstNameInput,lastNameInput,Desktop
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
RootFolder = Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Info")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fso.FolderExists(RootFolder) Then
    fso.CreateFolder(RootFolder)
End If
Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(RootFolder)
Do
    firstNameInput = inputbox("Please enter your name")
Loop Until firstNameInput <> ""

Do
    lastNameInput = inputbox("Enter your last name")
Loop Until lastNameInput <> ""

FirstFile = RootFolder &"\peopleInfo.txt"
If Not fso.FileExists(FirstFile) Then
    Call Write2File(RootFolder & "\peopleInfo.txt")
Else
    sFileNewName = GetNewName(FirstFile)
    Call Write2File(sFileNewName)   
End If
'************************************************************************************************************
Function GetNewName(sFile)
    Dim snamebase,sname,Count,sTarget,MaxIncrementation
    MaxIncrementation = 1000
    snamebase = Split(Right(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile,"\")),".")(0)
    sname = snamebase
    Count = 0
    While Count < MaxIncrementation
        sTarget = Folder & "\" & sname & ".txt"
        If fso.FileExists(sTarget) Then
            Count = Count + 1
            sName = snamebase & "(" & Count & ")"
        Else
            GetNewName = sTarget
            Exit Function
        End If
    Wend
End Function
'************************************************************************************************************
Sub Write2File(File)
    Dim fileStream
    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(File)
    fileStream.WriteLine firstNameInput
    fileStream.WriteLine lastNameInput
    fileStream.Close
End Sub
'************************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you I got it working, just wondering if you could help with this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469545/vbs-how-to-edit-a-text-file-through-inputbox?noredirect=1#comment47102903_29469545

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is caused by your line:

```
exists = fso.FolderExists(testPath)
```

It should be

```
exists = fso.FileExists(testPath)
```

as you are looking for a file, not a folder.

The second problem is caused by your line

```
count + 1
```

It should be

```
count = count + 1
```

to assign the new/increased value to count.

Comment: Thank you I got it working, I was wondering if you could help me with this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469545/vbs-how-to-edit-a-text-file-through-inputbox?noredirect=1#comment47102903_29469545

Answer (score 0):

Count is always starts at 1 because you say so. `Count = 1`. Store count in a file.

Comment: Sorry but I'm very new to programming, can you please show an example of storing Count = 1 into a file, thanks

Comment: Say what your goal is? Why would you want to create 1 file with 1 record per program run?