# Vbs How to edit a text file through inputbox

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a program that edits a text file every time you open it

Here is what I have:

```
Dim firstNameInput
Dim lastNameInput

firstNameInput = inputbox("Please enter your name")
lastNameInput = inputbox("Enter your last name")
```

The rest of the code has to edit 1 specific text file: `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Edit.txt` then write the name and last name on a new line

If there is anyone who could help I would be great full, thanks.

Comment: First of all did you check my reply here ???? ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468140/change-name-if-exists-when-creating-a-txt-file-in-vbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that to append data :

```
Option Explicit
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim ws,fso,RootFolder,MyFile,firstNameInput,lastNameInput,fileStream
Do
    firstNameInput = inputbox("Please enter your name")
Loop Until firstNameInput <> ""

Do
    lastNameInput = inputbox("Enter your last name")
Loop Until lastNameInput <> ""

Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
RootFolder = Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop")
MyFile = RootFolder & "\Edit.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fileStream = fso.OpenTextFile(MyFile,ForAppending,True)
fileStream.WriteLine String(50,"*")
fileStream.WriteLine "First name: " & firstNameInput
fileStream.WriteLine "Last name: " & lastNameInput
fileStream.Close
ws.run DblQuote(MyFile)
'*****************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*****************************************
```

Another version. Just give a try !

```
Option Explicit
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim ws,fso,RootFolder,MyFile,firstNameInput,lastNameInput,fileStream
Dim Question,Title
Title = "Put Informations in file"
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Call MyInputBox()
Do
    Question = MsgBox("Did you want to add another data to file",VbYesNo+VbQuestion,Title)
    If Question = VbYes Then
        Call MyInputBox()
    Else
        ws.run DblQuote(MyFile)
        Wscript.Quit()
    End If
Loop Until Question = VbNo
'********************************************************************
Sub MyInputBox()
    Do
        firstNameInput = inputbox("Please enter your name")
    Loop Until firstNameInput <> ""

    Do
        lastNameInput = inputbox("Enter your last name")
    Loop Until lastNameInput <> ""

    RootFolder = Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop")
    MyFile = RootFolder & "\Edit.txt"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fileStream = fso.OpenTextFile(MyFile,ForAppending,True)
    fileStream.WriteLine "First name: " & firstNameInput
    fileStream.WriteLine "Last name: " & lastNameInput
    fileStream.WriteLine String(30,"*")
    fileStream.Close
End Sub
'********************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'********************************************************************
```

Comment: Well what I mean is that every time I open the program it adds the info that has been inputted, for example when I open it the 1st time it writes that input data into `Edit.txt` Then when I open it again it need to add more of the info, and not over write it.

Comment: Thank you, does exactly what I want it to